# Is it possible to use SQL Server Analysis Services as Data Source?

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, birt

I need to connect directly BIRT reporting tool to database cube, I am trying but with no result, could any one help with a working approach...

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2704/developing-a-ssrs-report-using-a-ssas-data-source/

Comment: This is not related to SSRS. I've removed (pending) the incorrect tags. It relates to BIRT open source reporting.